# PHP Parse error: Invalid numeric literal in /home/8zK1VC/prog.php on line 6

Tags: php

simple code:

```
echo 089/3;
```

gives this error:

```
PHP Parse error: Invalid numeric literal in /home/8zK1VC/prog.php on line 6
```

why?

Comment: Because 089 is not the same as 89. With the leading zero you imply octal notation.

Comment: @MarkusZeller what does that mean?

Comment: Please read the PHP manual to understand. https://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.integer.php

Comment: PHP, like many (most) other languages uses the `0` (that is the _zero_) prefix for octal numbers. Since PHP8.1(I believe) you can now also use explicit `0o` (that is a `zero` followed by the letter `o`) notation for octal numbers- guess to make it more obvious (like `0x` for hexadecimal and `0b` for binary numbers).

Answer (score -1):

The reason you're getting that error is because you're attempting to divide an int data type that isn't properly formed. Integer shouldn't start with zero.

```
echo 89/3   // works
echo '089'/3   // works too
echo 089/3   // throws an error
```